# File rename failed in remote git repository

Tags: git

I am bit lost again with git. My situation is this:

I have a remote repository where I `push`ed my local repository. Then I noticed I had 2 docker files in it. One named `Dockerfile` the other named `Dockerfile (local_model)`. I also noticed that I needed only 1 `Dockerfile` and this has to be `Dockerfile (local_model)`.

In other words I needed to delete `Dockerfile` and then rename `Dockerfile (local_model)` to `Dockerfile`.

I used these commands to achieve it:

```
git rm --cached path/to/Dockerfile
git commit -m "Deleted a file"
git push -u origin master
```

which deleted the file in the remote repository (I checked it on browser and it seems to have worked).

Then I used:

```
git mv "path/to/Dockerfile (local_model)" "path/to/Dockerfile"
```

> fatal: destination exists,
>   source=path/to/Dockerfile
>   (local_model),
>   destination=path/to/Dockerfile

which prevented me from renaming the file because another file existed with the same name. I managed to rename the file by using:

```
git mv --force "path/to/Dockerfile (local_model)" "path/to/Dockerfile"
```

after all (and also applying `commit ...` and `push..` afterwards) but I got confused.

Where was the file that had the same name as my destination file? I know that this command affect the remote repository only so there shouldn't be any conflict with local repository, right?

Comment: Was the old dockerfile still on disk?

Comment: On my local disk you mean? Yes, but I thought that only the remote would be affected

Comment: The error was about the file being on your file system (because you only asked git to not track it anymore (git rm --cached then git commit) but the file was still there so when you asked the other file that git is tracking to be renamed to the same name (path) of a file that exists already on the working tree (even if git is not tracking it), then it warns you about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[eftshift0's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52555926/file-rename-failed-in-remote-git-repository#comment92050975_52555926) has the answer: the file Git was griping about, that `git mv --force` overwrote, was the *work-tree* copy.  What's going on here is that Git has a lot of copies of files!

#### Commits are permanent (well, mostly) and read-only, and freeze files forever

When you are using Git to make new commits, it's important to remember several things.  First, the *commits themselves* are the permanent records.  Each commit is or has:

- a snapshot of all the files that you told Git to freeze into that commit;
- your name (as author and committer), or the name of the author/committer if the commit was made by someone else;
- your (or someone else's) *log message* about why you made the commit; and—this part is crucial, but we won't cover it here because we're not concerned with how Git's history works yet—the *hash ID* of the commit's parent or parents.

The actual name of each commit is a big ugly hash ID, which Git makes up on the spot when you (or whoever) makes the commit.  Git guarantees that each big ugly hash ID will be unique, so that every commit has a different hash ID.  Once made, no one—not you nor Git—can ever *change* a commit: if you attempt this, and actually do change something and commit again, what you get is a *different* commit, with a new and different hash ID.  The old commit remains in the repository too.

In some cases you can tell Git to *forget about* a commit (really, a whole chain of commits), so that you can never find them again; eventually Git will clean them up and remove them.  But mostly, what we do with a Git repository is *add new commits*, while keeping all the existing commits intact.  We can't change any existing commit at all, so once made, it has a frozen copy of all of the files, saved forever in case you need them back out of the deep-freeze.

#### Frozen files are compressed and Git-only, so we must have a work-tree

Because Git keeps, forever (mostly), *every* version of *every* file you (or anyone) ever told it to save, these files would rapidly take up all your storage if Git just saved them as-is.  So the frozen files are compressed, sometimes very compressed, in a special Git-only format, *shared* among all the commits.  New freezes—new commits—just re-use old freezes from old commits whenever possible.  This is all automatic and behind the scenes, but it has a strong consequence.

If Git did not have a way to reconstitute / re-hydrate your freeze-dried files, you'd never be able to get *any* of them back!  There would be no `git checkout`.  That would be, in a word, bad.  So Git provides you a space in which it extracts (and un-freezes) your files, turning them back into usable files.  This space is your *work-tree* or *working tree*.

In general, you use `git checkout` to tell Git: *I'd like this here commit please.*  You use a *name* like `master`, but you're really picking a commit by its unique hash ID.  Git reconstitutes the files and puts them in your work-tree so that you can access them and work on them.

Git remembers which commit you chose (and its branch name): these are your *current commit*.  Git does this by attaching the name `HEAD` to the branch name.<sup>1</sup>  It remains your current commit until you do something to change which commit is your current commit—including `git checkout`, but also including making a *new* commit, which then *becomes* the current commit.  Anyway, obviously, at this point, we have two copies of each file.  If you have a file named `README.txt`, we can call one of them `HEAD:README.txt` and the other just plain `README.txt`.  The `HEAD` copy is Git-only and frozen for all time, and the work-tree copy is normal.

Git could stop here—it could have the frozen Git-only files saved forever in commits, plus the one work-tree copy you're working on or with.  But Git adds a third copy into the mix.

---

<sup>1</sup>Attaching `HEAD` to some branch name is sufficient to remember both your current branch *and* your current commit, because the branch name remembers the commit.  You can ask Git: *What's the branch name for `HEAD`?* and you get the branch; or you can ask Git: *What's the commit hash ID for `HEAD`?* and Git uses the branch name to find the commit.

---

#### The index

Git uses a trick here, partly for speed, partly for various other purposes.  Instead of taking the files out of the deep-freeze and reconstituting them and forgetting what it did, Git essentially *copies* the files out of the freezer into a more convenient location.  Here, they're still kept in Git's highly compressed form, but now they're *un-frozen*.

This third area—really a middle area *between* the commit and the work-tree—is called, variously, the *index*, the *staging area*, or the *cache*, depending on who / which bit of Git is doing the calling.  The first thing this index does is that it makes `git commit` **fast**.  Since files in the index (or staging area) are always already in the right *form*, all `git commit` has to do is freeze them.  Other version control systems have to poke around through your entire work-tree, examining every file carefully to see if it has changed, which may even involve re-compressing the file to its frozen form.  This takes a long time.  Git does not have to do that.

But this means that as you work, you have a *third* version of every file.  Not only is there a `HEAD:README.txt` to go with your work-tree `README.txt`, there's an *index* copy of `README.txt`, which we can call `:README.txt`.

When you run `git add` on a file, Git compresses the work-tree version of that file down and replaces the one that was in the index before.  Or, if it wasn't in the index at all before, now it is.  Either way, the new version of the file is now ready to go—all `git commit` has to do is freeze the pre-compressed file!

This is where `git rm` comes in.  If you have a file that's in your work-tree because it was in a commit, you—or Git anyway—have *three copies* of the file at your fingertips right now: `HEAD:file` in the current commit, `:file` in the index, and `file` in the work-tree.  Running `git rm file` removes *two* copies: the one in the index, and the one in the work-tree.  (It can't touch the frozen one because, well, it's frozen!)  Now that the file isn't in the index, it *won't* be in the *next* commit you make.

If you run `git rm --cached`, though, what Git does is remove *only* the index copy.  Now you have `HEAD:file` and `file` but no `:file`.  This means that the *next* commit you make won't have file `file` in it.  It's a bit hard to see what you did, though, because the index copy of each file is normally invisible.  If you use your normal computer tools to see what files you have, that shows you the *work-tree* files.

The `HEAD` copy of each file is also normally invisible, which has the same problem—but since committed files are frozen, we generally don't care.  We just use `git checkout` to switch to some other commit, if we want to see the files.  That updates the index and work-tree both, to match the other commit.  Then we can just look at the work-tree, because all three copies of all the files match.

#### `git status` tells you everything, in an abbreviated and thus useful form

Git makes new commits *from* the index.  So the index determines what you will commit.  This is why we can describe it as *what will be in the next commit you make.*  But the index is essentially invisible.  How will you know what will be in the next commit you make?

Running `git status` is how you find out what's going on with your index.

The first thing `git status` does is tell you about your current branch, i.e., it looks to see which *branch name* the special name `HEAD` is attached to.  That tells you where your next commit will go.

The rest of `git status`'s output tells you about *files staged for commit* and *files not staged for commit*.  Instead of listing *every* file in the index—which, in a big project, would be a whole lot of files—what `git status` does first is *compare* the index copies of every file to see what has changed in thre since the `HEAD` copies.  It doesn't need the exact difference, just a fast scan for *is the index copy **the same**, or **different**?*  (This is something that Git can do really quickly because of its internal frozen format.)

If the file in the index—the `:file` copy—is *different* from the `HEAD:file` copy, Git tells you that this file is *staged for commit*.  You know that it will be in the next commit, but more usefully, you *also* know that it will be *different* in the new snapshot.  Comparing the old (current `HEAD`) and proposed new commits, `file` will have *changed*.

Meanwhile, `git status` also compares the index copy of `:file` with the work-tree copy, `file`.  If these two are different, Git tells you that this file is *not staged for commit*.  This tells you that you could run `git add` right now to *copy* `file` to `:file`.

Note that you can have all three versions of `file` being all different!  In this case, it's **both** `staged for commit` *and* `not staged for commit`.  And, of course, you can have new files—files that are not in `HEAD`, but *are* in the index and work-tree now.  You can have *removed* files—files that *are* in `HEAD`, but are *not* in the index and work-tree now.

#### Being in the index is what makes a file tracked

The index and work-tree copies of the file are separate things.  This means you can have a file that's in the work-tree, but not in the index.  Such a file is an *untracked file*.  Note that it does not matter if the file is in the `HEAD` commit!  (If it *is* in the `HEAD` commit, it must be the case that it *was* in the index, and you've removed it from the index and just have not yet committed.)  Running `git status` will tell you about such files, complaining that they are untracked.

You can also have a file that's in the index but not in the work-tree.  This is a somewhat strange state of affairs, but happens if you use a non-Git command to remove a file.  Git doesn't really care too much that you have done this—it will still use the index copy for new commits—but `git status` will tell you about it: the file will be deleted in the index-vs-work-tree comparison.

You can have Git shut up about untracked files, by listing their names (or *glob patterns* like `*.tmp`) in your `.gitignore` files.  This doesn't *make* the file untracked!  It just makes Git shut up about them.  It has some other effects as well, but the main one is to shut Git up.  That's useful, because it makes the `git status` output *shorter*.

When `git status` tells you *only what you need to know*—that some files are different when Git runs a `git diff` from `HEAD` to index, and some files are different when Git runs a `git diff` from index to work-tree—then `git status` becomes as useful as possible.  You don't have to selectively pick over its output to find the useful stuff, because *files X and Y are staged, and Z is not staged* is exactly the useful stuff.  Two files will be different in the next commit, if you make it right now; file Z *could* be different too, if you `git add` it.

If you selectively remove files from only the index, or only the work-tree, you find yourself in these rather unusual corner cases.  Some of them *do* make sense; Git won't prevent any of them.  Git usually tries to be careful not to clobber untracked files, because they are not going to be frozen forever into new commits, unlike the tracked files.

Comment: Brilliant explanation.  Silly question: exactly what commands does the OP need to execute a) to verify things are squared away, and b) fix everything, if it's not squared away?

Comment: @paulsm4: Ultimately, the interesting parts are *what's in each commit* (`git checkout` to see, or use `git ls-tree -r <commit>` or similar to view the file names alone) and *what's in my work-tree right now that I can't afford to lose* (regular tools plus mostly just `git status`). If you want to look at the entire mostly-raw contents of the index, `git ls-files --stage` will do that, but it's not really a "useful to users" command.

Comment: Note that `git checkout` overwrites index and work-tree contents, so it's good to verify those *first*. Repair, if required, is harder and depends on what is wrong.